# laravel4 View::share usage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

i just made variable global...

```
public function _construct()
{
    $wait = 'available';
    View::share('wait', $wait); 

}
```

now how do i call this??in views?? is it just

```
echo $wait
For blade 
{{Session::get('wait')}}
```

iam getting an error message `iam getting an error message... Undefined variable:`

how to display it on views??

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT**

I've just noticed (after adding my answer) an error in your constructor - it's name is `_construct` with single underscore. It should be with double underscore `__construct` so correct the name and make sure if error is still present and if it is, read the rest of the answer.

**Rest of the answer**

The first thing you need to run `View::share` before `View::make` otherwise you will get this error.

So if you use somewhere:

```
$wait = 'available';
View::share('wait', $wait);

return  View::make('myview');
```

In your template you can simply use:

```
{{ $wait }}
```

and you will get output `available` for your variable and not any notice.

But you mentioned you put `View::share` in a constructor. Is it in your controller class or in parent class? If in parent, you should then execute it using `parent::__construct();` - you need to make sure that this constructor is launched at all, so you can even add `echo 'I'm running'; exit;` in this constructor to make sure it has been launched at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can call it just by using the variable $wait ;-)

Comment: Noo iam getting an error message... `Undefined variable:`